# Цикл вызова функций

Tags: c, массивы, функции, циклы, указатели

Язык Си.
Есть функции, типа:

```c
void func_0() {}
void func_1() {}
...
void func_n() {}
```

Можно ли каким-то образом создать цикл для вызова этих функций, чтобы не вызывать каждую вручную?

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   func_(i)(); // вызов i-той функции
```

Можно создать массив указателей на эти функции, но опять-таки как заполнить этот массив автоматически, не занося туда каждый указатель вручную?

Comment: А что понимается под автоматическим заполнением? Как примерно вы это видите?

Comment: ̀ ̀ ̀
void (*options[4])(void) = {func_0, func_1, func_2, func_3};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    (*options[i])(); // вызов i-той функции
 ̀ ̀ ̀
Как заполнить массив не вручную, а с помощью цикла? Например, если этих функций будет 100 штук.

Answer (score 2):

Нормального способа автоматизировать заполнение массива нет.

Самый лучше вариант - сделать как-то по-другому.

Можно использовать одну функцию:

```
void func_i(int i)
{
    switch (i) {...}
}
```

Если бы вы писали на С++, можно использовать лямбда-функции и помещать их сразу в массив указателей на функции:

```
void (*array[])() = {
    [](){...},
    [](){...},
    [](){...},
};
```

---

Запасной вариант:

> "Автоматизировать" процесс заполнения массива, возможно, можно при помощи серьезной макро-магии, но конечный результат будет все равно таким. — (c) AnT

Вот она эта магия, прямиком из (отвратительного) Boost.Preprocessor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/not_equal.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/for.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>

#define MACRO_FOR_PRED(r, state) BOOST_PP_NOT_EQUAL( BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, state), BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, state)) )
#define MACRO_FOR_OP(r, state) ( BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, state)), BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, state), BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 2, state) )
#define MACRO_FOR_MACRO(r, state) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 2, state) (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, state))
#define MACRO_FOR(from, to, macro) BOOST_PP_FOR((from, to, macro), MACRO_FOR_PRED, MACRO_FOR_OP, MACRO_FOR_MACRO)

void func_0() {puts("func_0");}
void func_1() {puts("func_1");}
void func_2() {puts("func_2");}

int main()
{
    #define LOOP_BODY(x) BOOST_PP_CAT(func_,x),
    void (*array[])(void) = { MACRO_FOR(0, 2, LOOP_BODY) }; // 0 и 2 - номера первой и последней функции.
    #undef LOOP_BODY

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof array / sizeof array[0]); i++)
        array[i]();
}
```

<kbd>[Запустить код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fefb5cf121177945)</kbd>

(Переделал пример [отсюда](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/).)

Минусы:

- Количество функций ограничено числом `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_MAG` (256 по умолчанию; можно поменять, перегенерировав библиотечные хедеры).
- Номера первой и последней функции в массиве должны быть известны на этапе компиляции (препроцессирования). Их даже нельзя поместить в константные переменные, только в макросы.
- Некоторое замедление компиляции.

Comment: Вопрос вроде по си, а у вас примеры на плюсах.

Comment: @0xdb Точно, не заметил. исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Это "вручную" или не "вручную"?

```
void (*const functions[N])() = 
{
  func_0,
  func_1,
  ...
  func_n
};

for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  functions[i]();
```

"Автоматизировать" процесс заполнения массива, возможно, можно при помощи серьезной макро-магии, но конечный результат будет все равно таким.

P.S. В языке С однако лучше `(void)`, а не `()`.

Comment: А что если таких функций будет 100 штук: все 100 штук вручную записывать в массив?

Comment: @KirillSomov А зачем вам может понадобиться 100 функций? Какую конкретно проблему вы пытаетесь решить? Не получится заменить все это на одну функцию, внутри которой будет `switch` от `0` до `99`?

Comment: В моём случае функций 10. Реализовал я таким же способом, но затем возник чисто теоретический вопрос можно ли это "автоматизировать".